# .Net и хранение секретного токена

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим есть WPF программа, которая работает клиентом через сетевое соединение. Пользователь программы ввел свои имя:пароль и в ответ от сервера программа получила секретный ключ или токен, который используется для дальнейшей работы программы с сервером. **Существует ли в .Net возможность создать некую защищенную область памяти, в которой можно было бы хранить на время сеанса работы программы этот ключ?** Это нужно для того чтобы исключить возможность "подсмотреть" этот ключ во время пошаговой декомпиляции.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, **от кого** вы хотите защититься? Опишите вашу модель угроз, приведите сценарий, которого вы хотели бы избежать.

Comment: securestring? https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Возможно, что это окажется полезным http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread1728117.html

Comment: @VladD предполагается использовать ограничение на сеанс работы определенным серийным номером HDD, т.е. один пользоватеь = один компьютер.

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev спасибо.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов спасибо.

Comment: @Bulson: Ничего не понял. Какой ваш проблемный сценарий? Вы боитесь, что пользователь, который хозяин своей машины и вполне может запустить программу под эмулятором, узнает состояние её переменных? Ну так этого не предотвратить, он всё же полный хозяин своей машины.

Comment: @VladD именно это, во время выполнения программы можно подсмотреть значения ее переменных, так вот уже выяснилось, что для защиты от этого есть спец.класс `SecureString`

Comment: @Bulson: Эээ... Ну запустит юзер программу под отладчиком и прочитает значение этой самой securestring точно так же, как и программа это делает. Как-то несерьёзно.

Comment: @Bulson: Например, через `Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx#interop

Comment: @VladD а зачем, тогда мелкомягкие озаботились и создали такой класс? Как раз чтобы защитится от отладчика.

Comment: @Bulson: От отладчика защититься никак нельзя. Это они чтобы защититься от чтения памяти всякими вирусами, которые могут просто просканировать память. Защищаться от пользователя бесполезно, он может вообще всё. Он может в конце-концов подложить в GAC Assembly со _своей_ версией `SecureString`.

Comment: @VladD ну, это понятно, что на любой хитрый болт можно найти отвертку. Т.е. вы хотите сказать, что все эти потуги полностью бесполезны, примерно как и обфускация кода, и нужно плюнуть на это жирно, потому как все это пустая трата сил и времени. Так что ли?

Comment: @Bulson: Обфускация кода призвана не защититься абсолютно от взлома, а лишь увеличить его сложность и тем самым уменьшить его шансы. А SecureString вовсе не для этого, насколько я понимаю. Хуже того, она облегчает задачу взломщику: просто можно поставить breakpoint на её конструктор :)

Comment: Идея `SecureString` в том, что вы, как разработчик, контролируете жизнь такой строки (этот тип не зря сделан disposable), и её содержимое шифруется, в то время как обычный `String` может висеть в памяти сколь угодно долго, так что злоумышленник может сохранить дамп процесса в файл, скажем, на флешку, а потом вытащить пароль в открытом виде с помощью WinDbg и SOS. Вот почему у `SecureString` нет конструктора, принимающего строку. Пошаговая декомпиляция здесь не при чем.